# Exotic Definitions of Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition, big-list

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253514/a-semigroup-x-is-a-group-iff-for-every-g-in-x-exists-x-in-x-such-that) I was wondering, whether there are alternative definitions of groups, namely ones different from the usual 4 axioms. I already suspected that the category theorists have one and indeed, a group can also be defined as a groupoid with only one object. Do you know of any other?

And if you happen to know any weird ones, I also welcome exotic definitions of algebraic objects other than groups :)

Comment: I'd call the "Eudoxus construction" of the real numbers "exotic". You can read about it on Google or see a brief intro to it at the bottom of the wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers

Comment: [Related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2282063/104041)

Comment: [Related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2256286/104041)

Comment: [Definitions of a group using just one axiom each.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3614165)

Comment: Let $G$ be a non-empty set with an associative binary operation, written as multiplication, such that for all $a,b\in G$ there exist unique $c,c'$ with $ca=b=ac'.$

Comment: @Shaun If you post "Definitions of a group using just one axiom each" as an answer and elaborate a bit more (maybe write down the axioms or even show a bit of the proof), I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Let $S$ be a semigroup. Then $S$ is a group if and only if

$$aS=S=Sa$$

for all $a\in S$, where $aS=\{ as\in S\mid s\in S\}$ and $Sa=\{ sa\in S\mid s\in S\}$.

---

A semigroup $S$ is a group if there exists an $e$ in $S$ such that for all $a$ in $S$, $ea=a$ and for all $x$ in $S$ there exists a $y$ in $S$ such that $yx=e$.

Comment: This is an amazing definition, that I've never seen before :)

Comment: Was thinking, could you also say $(G,\cdot \star\cdot, \cdot^{-1})$ is a group if and only if $G\star G^{-1} = G$ elementwise?

Comment: Thank you, @DanielDonnelly. I think so too. Regarding your question: I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another funny definition of a group. (This was an old *American Mathematical Monthly* problem but I've lost the reference.)

**Proposition.** A semigroup $S$ is a group if there are elements $a,b\in S$ such that:
(1) for each $x\in S$ there is a unique $y\in S$ such that $xy=a$;
(2) for each $x\in S$ there is a unique $y\in S$ such that $yx=b$.

**Proof.** Let $ac=a$. Then the equation $xy=c$ is equivalent to $axy=a$ Hence, for each $x\in S$ there is a unique $y\in S$ such that $xy=c$; that is, the hypothesis holds with $a$ replaced by $c$. Since $cc=c$, we can assume that $aa=a$; likewise we can assume that $bb=b$.

Let $a=bu$ and $b=va$; then $ba=bbu=bu=a$ and $ba=vaa=va=b$, so $a=b$.

For any $x\in S$ there is an element $y\in S$ such that $yx=b=a$; then $yxa=a=yx$, so $xa=x$. Thus $a$ is a right identity. Since every element has a right inverse with respect to $a$, the semigroup $S$ is a group.